Unknown Kotlin JVM target Problem in Flutter with IntelliJ
I am developing a flutter application with IntelliJ. I want to add the edge_detection package. In their official documentation, it says:

The plugin code is written in kotlin 1.8.0 so the same has to be set to the android project of yours for compilation. Change the kotlin_version to 1.8.0 in your android/build.gradle file. ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
However, it seems recent flutter versions do not have the 'buildscript' block in the build.gradle file. So after looking around for some time, I found out settings.gradle now includes the way to update the kotlin version, and so I did.
When trying to run the application, I encountered the following error:


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':edge_detection:compileDebugKotlin'.
Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':edge_detection:compileDebugKotlin'.
Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
> Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21

This is my android/build.gradle file:
plugins {
    // ...

    // Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.4.2' apply false

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    subprojects {
        afterEvaluate { project ->
            if (project.hasProperty('android')) {
                project.android {
                    if (namespace == null) {
                        namespace project.group
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}




My settings.gradle file:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
    id "com.google.gms.google-services" version "4.4.2" apply false
}

include ":app"


And my app/build.gradle file:
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.new_flutter_demo"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.new_flutter_demo"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdk = 23
        targetSdk = flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:33.6.0')
}

I am not quite sure how to solve this problem. This question may have been answered before, but I cannot seem to find it. So I would really appreciate it if anyone provided proper guidance.
